# PHP reset Password

Tags: php, passwords, reset

I am confused about how to encrypt the new password to go in the database. When I enter the password it will encrypt and check the database correct and to verify for the new password it will just change it to plain text.

```
if (count($_POST) > 0) {
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT *from users WHERE id='" . $_SESSION["id"] . "'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    if (MD5(mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST["currentPassword"] == $row["password"]))) {
        mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE users set password='" . $_POST["newPassword"] . "' WHERE id='" . $_SESSION["id"] . "'");
        $message = "Password Changed";
    } else
        $message = "Current Password is not correct";
}
```

Comment: You should be using [password_hash](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    // password encryption for security.

$salt = mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
$salt = base64_encode($salt);
$salt = str_replace('+', '.', $salt);
$hash = crypt($pass, '$2y$10$'.$salt.'$');

//echo ("".$hash."<br />\n");
```

`$pass` is the password from the password input

save `$hash` to the database

verify the password with that got from the database `$hash`

```
if(password_verify($pass, $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
```

update and try that procedure

Answer (score 1):

for simple application you can use base64_encode() to encrypt and store it into database when new password is entered. and for login also encrypt the entered password and match it with database.

your code:

```
if (count($_POST) > 0) 
{
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT *from users WHERE id='" .     $_SESSION["id"] . "'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $entered_password = base64_encode($_POST["currentPassword"]);
    $new_password = base64_encode($_POST["newPassword"]);
    $id =  $_SESSION["id"] ;
    if ($entered_password  == $row["password"]))) {

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE users set password='" . $new_password . "' WHERE id='" .$id. "'");
        $message = "Password Changed";
    } else
        $message = "Current Password is not correct";
}
```

its a simply way.

Answer (score 1):

```
//password encryption

$user_password = "1234";
$hash_pass = password_encryption($user_password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost'=>10);

//"$user_password"-password obtained from the user input
//"$hash_pass" -encrypted password stored in a database

//verify the user password with that obtained from the database

if(password_verify($user_password, $hash_pass)){
     echo "password is valid";
}else{
     echo "password is not valid";
}
```

try this out.

Comment: i hope this will help you more better